# Customizing serializers format

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'd like to customize DRF serializers so that instead of parsing / outputting say, "contact" objects like so:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "email": "bar@example.com"
}
```

It would do wrap it inside a "contact" attribute in the JSON, e.g.

```
{
    "contact": {
        "name": "foo",
        "email": "bar@example.com"
    }
}
```

Similarly, the ListSerizalizer would return a list of contacts like so:

```
{
    "contacts": [
       <item1>,
       <item2>...
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Cheers
-JM

Answer (score 1):

You can override `to_representation` method to customize the serialization.

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    return {"contact": ret}
```

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, although it seems I also need to override to_internal_value as well so that it works both ways. Now I guess I need to work out how to handle lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two serializers one for Contact and second one for contacts. Than you have to do next:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # it should contain your fields

class AddrBook(serializers.Serializer):
    contacts = ContactSerializer(many=True)
```

You can find more about nested serializers there https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects